# "Use Html File" Template is not working in my ECM

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

I am not sure what I did wrong. When I click on Use Html File, no action is performed. I checked everything and couldnt solve this.

[image]

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Any error messages in the browser?  How about the Sitecore logs?  Which version of Sitecore/ECM?  Have you tried another browser?

Comment: It was my mistake. It was not showing because of popup blocker. Actually it didn't show any warning. Anyway thanks craig